# Change the src of img with general names

Tags: jquery

I have created a code that changes the src of an img in some cases. It works well:

HTML:

```
$('#image').attr('src','img/1.jpg');
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#image').attr('src','img/1.jpg');    
$('#image').attr('src','img/1-small.jpg');
```

I have a lot of img, my question is: can I make this work with any name of the file?. For instance

```
$('#image').attr('src','anyName.jpg');
$('#image').attr('src','anyName-small.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ID should be unique.** `$('#image')` will select the only single/first element having the ID `image`.

To update the `src` attribute value of multiple elements [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) can be used as follow:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace(/(\.jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, '-small$1');
});
```

The regex `/(\.jpe?g|png|gif)$/i` will match the extension of images and add that in the first captured group-`$1` which can be used in the replacement.